# Translating string characters to integers in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Bit of an amateur here, so hopefully you can bear with me. I've written a script that parses .mp4 video-header metadata and consolidates relevant data points as variables. In order for the script to perform it's task, the "Hours:Minutes:Seconds" data i'm gathering from the header need to be converted to a single integer with unit milliseconds. Below is an example of how the variables are defined, and it echoes the correct value no matter which set of data I point it at....

*creation_hour= grep ".creationdate" mediatest.txt | cut -b 55-56 #pulls creation hour*

....but when I try to perform the arithmetic necessary to convert $creation_hour from hours to milliseconds I'm unsuccessful.

I've been browsing these boards for hours looking for a solution, and have been unsuccessful with all suggested solutions i've encountered.

Comment: What is the content of `$creation_hour`?

Comment: Write some example of what you have and what you need to get

Comment: creation_hour=$(grep ".creationdate" mediatest.txt | cut -b 55-56)

Comment: $creation_hour echoes a value of 0. $creation_hour is only one of 11 numeric variables i'm defining by pulling characters from a .txt file. When I echo all 12 characters and execute the resulting readout is:  +40.7010
-073.9098
 2019
12
23
 2019-12-23
00
57
18
00:57:18
2 
13

Comment: grep ".creationdate" mediatest.txt | cut -d' ' -f 7

Comment: It works now thanks Serg and Wilx! I'm really new to this!

Answer (score 0):

Use delimeter ' ' for cut and field number 7:

```
grep ".creationdate" mediatest.txt | cut -d' ' -f 7
```